# How do we add tolerance for Rglpk R package

Tags: r, linear-programming, glpk

I am new to R Gplk...
How do i add a tolerance to my Rglpk linear programming problem.

I am currently getting false for the following codes

```
equal_checks<-all((abs(mat_con[dir=="=",]%*%sol$solution-rhs[dir=="="])<=1e-7))
less_checks<-all(((mat_con[dir=="<=",]%*%sol$solution)-rhs[dir=="<="])<=1e-7)
greater_checks<-all(((mat_con[dir==">=",]%*%sol$solution)-rhs[dir==">="])>=-1e-7)
```

Even though status code is zero. i am getting is has something to do with the convergence tolerance.

How do i change the tolerance?

Regards
James

Comment: There is a `tol_bnd = 1.0e-7`. I would not recommend changing that. Note that scaling and presolving has an effect on the tolerances of the final (unscaled, post-solved) solution.

Comment: Hi Erwin. thanks for your comment..

i did try before

Rglpk_solve_LP(...,control=list(tm_limit=30000,tol_bnd=1e-9)) but doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: I don't think the Rglpk passes that on to glpk. The rglpk docs don't list this as a supported option in the control list.